# TYPO3-Extension: relative path for CSS image properties

Tags: css, relative-path, typo3-6.2.x

I have some images in my `MyExtension/Resources/Public/Icons/` directory.
In the `MyExtension/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt` file I added some CSS configuration stuff using `background: url("mypic.gif");`.

The question is: how should the relative path for the images in the CSS-file be set?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it depends where your css file is located.

If the CSS file is e.g. located under MyExtension/Resources/Public/Css/main.css and your images are in the the directory you mentioned above, then your path would be.

```
    background: url("../Icons/mypic.gif");
```

Comment: Yeah, if it was that easy! ;) CSS-file isn't in `Public` directory, it is in `MyExtension/Configuration/TypoScript`, as I mentioned.  
That's why I cannot figure out what is the directory CSS file search starts with.

Comment: O.k. I see. Then it is hard to use a relative path, because your base path changes for every page.
But you could use the absolute path. "/typo3conf/ext/MyExtension/Resources/Public/Icons/mypic.gif"

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I've also tried a complete absolute path - also with no luck.